# What sort of chords are these?

Tags: piano, composition

I have been listening to a lot of Asian film music, and notice that they all have a certain feel to it by using this sort of chord:

[image]

What sort of chord is that? Is it an inversion of a suspended chord or something? I've noticed many other artists like Yiruma use it, but I'm not quite sure what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first chord could be written as `Fmaj13(#11)` and the second one as `G6/9`. What might make it sound special for you is the use of perfect fifths and perfect fourths instead of (major or minor) thirds. Note that in the lower voice you have quite a few perfect fifths (and also perfect fourths), and the top chord is an inversion of the quartal chord `b-e-a`.